# Trying to data pull from multiple excel sheets with Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to create a python program that will take data from multiple excel sheets and I am kinda stuck at the moment:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt 
workbook1 = xlrd.open_workbook('Z:\Public\Safety\SafetyDataPullProject\TestFile.xlsx', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook1.sheet_by_index('Sheet1')
sheet.cell(5, 5).value
```

This is my code currently this produces a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\python things\Datapull2.py", line 4, in <module>
    worksheet = workbook1.sheet_by_index('Sheet1')
  File "C:\Users\gomcrai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 432, in sheet_by_index
    return self._sheet_list[sheetx] or self.get_sheet(sheetx)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I just wanna take the information from the cell(s) I've marked and drop them into a newly created excel sheet. If anyone could help me please let me know.

Side note: I know these things would probably be easier in VB but I am practicing python.

Comment: You are using a `sheet_by_index` method, which requires an index (integer number); you probably wanted `sheet_by_name` instead, as `'Sheet1'` is a name, not index.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sheet_by_name`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Book.sheet_by_name-method) not [`sheet_by_id`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Book.sheet_by_index-method).

`sheet_by_id` takes position (integer) as parameter and return sheet at that position.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to fetch records from multiple sheets, try storing total number of sheets in a variable and iterate through that variable. It should look something like:-

```
import xlrd
import xlwt 
workbook1 =xlrd.open_workbook('Z:\Public\Safety\SafetyDataPullProject\TestFile.xlsx', on_demand = True)
sheet_no = len(workbook1.sheet_names())
for sheets in range(0,int(sheet_no)-1):
      worksheet = workbook1.sheet_by_index(sheets)
      print(worksheet.cell(5,5).value)
```

Please refer the [documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more info.